# FCM notifications sent but never received in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

**Update...before I ever posted**

I actually discovered the solution before I posted this but thought I'd post it anyway in hopes of saving someone else's time.

As a last resort I tried deleting the APNs Authentication Key and reverting back to the certificate for the application in Firebase Cloud Messaging project settings. That fixed it. Below is the message I'd intended to post.

I'm attempting to push notifications to subscribers of a specific topic using Firebase FCM. According to the Cloud Messaging console the notifications are being sent but they're never received by a device subscribed to the topic. I'm also not receiving test messages sent via the console.

I've confirmed the following:

- APNS is properly configured for my project. I was able to receive a
  notification on a device using a testing site
  (https://www.apnstester.com/apns/)
- The topic is being subscribed to or at least subscribeToTopic doesn't
  return an error.
- I'm receiving a remote instance ID token.
- I'm receiving an APNS device token

I've also tried:

- Enabling and disabling swizzling (and yes, when it's disabled I'm
  setting the APNS token)
- Deleting and reloading my APNs Authentication Key
- Updating the Firebase framework
- Removing and re-adding the GoogleService-Info.plist

I should point out this is old app (hence the Objective-C swizzling) and notifications worked fine in the past. Any suggestions or advice?

Comment: Have you confirmed your certificate is still valid and able to receive push notifications on the device without using firebase?

Comment: Can you please post your Payload so I can help you.

Comment: @RushabhCShah the issue is fixed, as I said in the second paragraph deleting the APNs Authentication Key and resorting to a certificate fixed the problem. I'll look into why and if I find an answer I'll post here.

Comment: @BrandonStillitano as I pointed out in the posting I was able to receive a notification sent via apnstester.com hence my authentication key was still valid